# How to select Last 10 days older order from my database

Tags: php, sql

I have these table in my database:

```
id  Name    Order Date
1   A       29-Dec
2   B       15-Dec
3   C       12-Oct
4   A       15-Dec
5   B       15-Sep
6   A       15-Sep
7   B       15-Aug
8   C       15-Aug
9   A       15-Jul
```

Expected Output:-

```
Name    QTY     Last Order Date
A       4       29-Dec
B       3       15-Dec
C       2       12-Oct
```

How to do this, Please help.

Also I have to select only those record whose last order date is greater than 10 days.

**The purpose behind this query is to send such customer a notification who are not ordering since 10 days**. How to do this, Please help...

Comment: Select orders where date is older than 10 days..

Answer (score 1):

Try this (assuming order date is of datetime datatype

```
select name,count(*) as qty, max([order date]) as [order date] from table
where [order date]>dateadd(day,-10,getdate())
group by name
```